# How to encode text to UTF-8 without knowing beforehand the encoding used?

Tags: text-processing

I have seen a lot of ways to convert text to UTF-8 but they all need to specify the current text encoding used.

Is there a way to batch convert multiple files into UTF-8 without having to care about what they used before?

Comment: There is no fool-proof way to determine the encoding of a file. Any solution would be based on heuristics. If you know the language of the text (Spanish, Greek, Russian...), those heuristics can be improved by guessing the encoding based on the number of valid words in that language that can be found in the text for each possible encoding (using a dictionary).

Comment: Well I did a little of research and seems you can find the encoding of a file with file -i file. So probably can do a loop where the output of file -i file is used in the command? @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: `file` uses very simple/limited heuristics. For instance `echo εύρηκα | iconv -t iso8859-7 | file -i -` returns `charset=iso-8859-1` instead of `iso-8859-7`. It thinks it's `åýñçêá` encoded in iso8859-1 even though that's not a word in any language (contrary to `εύρηκα` which is a word in Greek).

Comment: Look at things like `uchardet`, python `chardet` for better heuristics

Answer (score 3):

This is a dificult problem, but I have it very often.
I built a set of scripts with different approaches and I will show a simple one (ensureutf8 in European latin context)

- for each file, ask for his type and charset (`file -i`)
- decide what to do for common cases, keeping a backup.
- in many cases... do nothing!
- in some cases use a default (in the example CP1252 / latin1)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $charset;

for(@ARGV){
  $charset="?";
  next if /.bak$/;
  my $type = `file -b -i '$_'`;   ### use file -i for  charset and type
  if($type =~ /(\S+);\s+charset=(\S+)/){$type=$1; $charset=lc($2)};

  next    if($charset eq "utf-8") ;
  next    if($charset eq "binary") ;
  next    if($charset eq "us-ascii")  ;
  next    if($type eq "application/postscript");

  if($type eq "application/xml"){
    rename($_ ,"$_.bak");
    system ("xmllint --encode utf-8 '$_.bak' > '$_'\n")  }
  elsif($charset eq "non-iso" or $charset eq "unknown-8bit" ) {
    rename($_ ,"$_.bak");
    system ("iconv -f CP1252 -t utf-8 '$_.bak' > '$_'\n")  }  ## DANGER
  elsif($charset eq "utf-16le"){
    rename($_ ,"$_.bak");
    system ("iconv -f $charset  -t utf-8 '$_.bak' > '$_'\n")  }
  elsif($charset eq "iso-8859"  or  $charset eq "iso-8859-1"){
    rename($_ ,"$_.bak");
    system ("iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 '$_.bak' > '$_'\n")  }
  else { print "HELP: '$type:$charset' '$_'\n"; }
}
```

This is not a universal tool, but it may be useful as a starting point for implementing your own heuristic.